# Saved Cases not showing

Tags: civicase

On occasion, a Case that has been added to an Individual will not show up under the cases section of the individual summary for anywhere between 5 and 40 minutes. I have tested this myself, but because it doesn't happen every time, I am finding it difficult to find a solution. 
I have looked into the error log and found nothing for the times when these cases have been created, and our site doesn't have an update time anywhere in the range of of 40 minutes which seems to rule out any update issue. 
Has anyone else come across this problem, and if so have you managed to rectify it?

Comment: Can you include CiviCRM version and CMS

Comment: The tabs (activities, cases, etc) on a contact are cached, even if you switch between tabs. Did you navigate completely away from the contact to another page in between checks?